# problem in xml parsing and showing data in android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i have to parse the data from url and show in list.I have parsed url acc to sample code. I have extended the main class to the default handler class. and used main,start and end tag.I have parsed the url acc to below code

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://asia.vmsc.vmsplay.com/vmsc.asmx/GetCountries");

     // Add your data
      List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("AccountId","vmsfree48jfwe83dwe8"));
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Countries","US"));
        // nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Language","en"));
         UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
         httppost.setEntity(formEntity);

     // Execute HTTP Post Response
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent(); 

     SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
        MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
        reader.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        reader.parse(new InputSource(is));          
        sitesList = MyXMLHandler.sitesList;

        countryname=new String[sitesList.getisocountrycode().size()];
        isocountrycode =new String[sitesList.getisocountrycode().size()];
        countrycode=new String[sitesList.getisocountrycode().size()];
        idd=new String[sitesList.getisocountrycode().size()];
        image=new String[sitesList.getisocountrycode().size()];
        image1=new String[sitesList.getisocountrycode().size()];


        for (int j = 0; j < sitesList.getisocountrycode().size(); j++) {
            countryname[j] = sitesList.getcountryname().get(j);
            System.out.println(" id "+sitesList.getcountryname().get(j));
            isocountrycode[j]=sitesList.getisocountrycode().get(j);
            System.out.println("title "+sitesList.getisocountrycode().get(j));
            countrycode[j] = sitesList.getcountrycode().get(j);
            System.out.println("desc "+sitesList.getcountrycode().get(j));
            idd[j] = sitesList.getProductcount().get(j);
            System.out.println("prociunt "+sitesList.getProductcount().get(j));
            image[j] = sitesList.getidd().get(j);
            System.out.println("image "+sitesList.getidd().get(j));
            System.out.println("image length  "+sitesList.getidd().get(j).length());
            image1[j] = sitesList.getImage1().get(j);
            System.out.println("image1 "+sitesList.getImage1().get(j));
```

But still I am not getting data that I have parsed ,,,

Can anyone tell where I have done wrong

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it s not good thing to publish you confidentiality in public site. 
>   second thing is that you have to call this 
>   http://asia.vmsc.vmsplay.com/vmsc.asmx?op=GetCountries
>   and pass your parameter then after 
>   http://asia.vmsc.vmsplay.com/vmsc.asmx/GetCountries 
>   then after you can get value from it.
>   always keep habit to print responce in logcat and then you judge that " post this issue to any site or not".

Comment: @scoprpio ok,,,,,,actually i was struck in xml parsing,,so wanted to learn.,....So posted here

Comment: ya it s alright but you never display your confidentiality. you can also send us to take a photo by print-screen. and skip those confidentiality data

Comment: well can u please have a look at my code and can edit that code,,

Answer (score 0):

What about changing your parameter "Countries" for "CountryCode". By the way it is not a good practice to publish your credentians on a public forum.

Comment: this url i am using for practise,,,,